# Mobile Selection List - Hide Default Option

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

In a mobile selection list how do you hide / remove the first default display item from the list? When viewing mobile select it will pop up a window with all the options, how do you remove the default "select an option" item?

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="">Default Label</option>
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to omit the "Default Label" as an option (not disable it but remove it entirely) when the mobile window pops up.

Comment: Posted - pretty basic but might give a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply remove the display of the default option:

```
select .default
{
    display: none;
}
```

and add default class to the default `<option>`

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="" class="default">Default Label</option>
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/1345/)**

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite way is to make the default option `disabled`

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="" disabled>Default Label</option>
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

This way, once the user clicks the dropdown, they have to choose one of the options, as the default is no longer available to them.

Answer (score 0):

If by "selection" you mean a select element, then you can just include a blank option.

```
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Selection 1</option>
  <option value="2">Selection 2</option>
</select>
```

This will give the effect of an empty  element until the user makes a choice.

Comment: I wan to label my select still, so it is asking for a response. I added code to my main question, hopefully that helps.